# Shovel plugin not transferring existing messages to destination queue

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I'm trying to copy all the messages in queue (Q1) to another queue (Q2) running on a different machine.

I'm using the shovel plugin and both nodes are running amqp 091. I've tested the connection and if I set the destination queue to a non-existing one, it does indeed create a new queue on the separate machine so I know the connection works.

```
rabbitmqctl set_parameter shovel test '{"src-uri": "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672", "src-queue": "q1", "ack-mode": "on-confirm", "dest-uri": "amqp://guest:guest@host:5672", "dest-queue": "q2"}'
```

I expected the plugin to transfer all existing messages to Q2, however they're not being transferred. Does the shovel plugin not do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the messages were not in the `Ready` state. I had to kill my celery worker and then the messages transferred successfully.